# Organize java imports in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

In my source files I have sections that looks like following:

```
// ----- <begin_imports/>
import javax.ejb.EJB;

// ----- <end_imports/>
```

Eclipse adds java import declarations near the begining of source file, which is default behaviour.

I would like to customize place where Eclipse adds imports, to be precise I would like Eclipse to insert new import delcarations between these two markers (begin_import and end_impots).

For example, when I use NewClass from newPackage Eclispe should add import in the following way:

```
// ----- <begin_imports/>
import newPackage.NewClass;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

// ----- <end_imports/>
```

not near the beginning of source file after package definition.

**EDIT**

I am using model-driven development in this case, ans substantial part of my code is tool generated. Then I manually enter missing parts. Manually entered code is placed between some tags in order to preserve those sections when I tweak the model and regenerate code.

The thing is that I cannot modify code generation tool which doesn't play nice with import sections, beacause I cannot force imports to go between import section tags, which are preserved during code generation.

This can be cumbersome because when I tweak model and regenerate code, all imports for manual coding are lost and I have to import them again.

Comment: Why do you need the markers? `import` statements always go between `package` statements and the actual class.

Comment: And Eclipse usually "hides" the imports anyway.

Comment: If the tool is that dump, you should throw it away. Tools should make your life simpler, not more complicated. But maybe the settings within Preferences ‣ Java ‣ Code Style ‣ Code Templates can help…

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how the import tags are ordered, but they will always be between the package and class declarations.

If you want to customize the sorting, go to "Window/Preferences". There navigate to "Java/Code Style/Organize Imports"
In that window you can define custom packages and in what order do you want to show them (for example, put all "newPackage" imports before the "javax" imports)